# How to communicate with an external Python process? (not a subprocess)

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing

The other python process was launched externally, only the process identifier is known. This external process is not a subprocess launched from a python process. The path to both processes could be the same. How do I communicate with that process? How can I easily send python data types between these processes?

Best regards,
Czarek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can accept communicating between the processes using a tcp connection, you could use zeromq. http://zeromq.org/

See these threads for examples:

- [interprocess communication in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python)
- [how to communicate two separate python processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952408/how-to-communicate-two-separate-python-processes)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that I have to act as some kind of server (listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:5555). This might trigger a firewall asking user to allow/deny it, right? Are there any other alternatives that act more like native IPC messaging seen in C++ programs?

Comment: I've just found out that there are a few transports available in ZeroMQ: INPROC, IPC, MULTICAST, TCP. Looks like zmq_ipc is what I'm looking for: http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-ipc